# getImage()/drawImage() makes Java-Applet stop working

Tags: java, swing, applet, graphics2d, japplet

I'm making a 2D Java Game using JApplet. For the Graphics I obviously use `Graphics` respectively `Graphics2D`. My Problem: I want to display an image in my `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. The picture is located in the same directory as the HTML5-File (in which the Applet is implemented) and the class files. Without the following code snippet, the applet works fine (except there's no image, obviously). But as soon as I add it to the class, the Applet doesn't start (in the Browser!). It won't display anything, and I don't get an exception.

Code:

```
Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) g;
Image img = getImage(getDocumentBase(), "img.PNG");
gg.drawImage(img, 70, 50, this);
gg.finalize();
```

Please note that I have Java Version 8 Update 51 installed and that I have the URL of the HTML5-File on my whitelist in the Java Control Panel (So I won't get a security-error). I tried the applet in Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Never** read in an image from within a painting method such as `paint` or `paintComponent`. Even if this were successful (it's not in your case), it will needlessly result in re-reading the image in multiple times and slowing down your program's perceived responsiveness -- the last thing that you want to do.
2. Instead read the image in once and store it in a variable.
3. Your problem has to be that you're not looking for the image in the right place -- with the right path. I recommend that you obtaine your Image as a resource from a URL or InputStream and use `ImageIO.read(...)` to read it in. You will need to find the correct path to the image, something hard for us to guess given your current question, but you will want to use a path relative to your class file locations.
4. This, `gg.finalize();`, is dangerous code and should not be there; get rid of this line.